# Serilog - convert level to syslog standard

Tags: serilog, azure-iot-edge

I am working on an Azure IoT Edge container and we are using Serilog.  Microsoft recommends outputting the log text to the console window in the format shown in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-retrieve-iot-edge-logs?view=iotedge-2020-11.  It would output a line like this to the console:

`<6> 2022-06-15 13:05:44.790 +00:00 [INF] - Received direct method call - ping`

My question is - how can I display the level twice?  The second is easy ({level:u3}), but how can I convert the level to a syslog number at the beginning of the line?  The number reference is at the beginning of the article above.  I thought about a text formatter, but I need the level formatted two different ways and was not sure that would work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a TextFormatter

```
internal class ConsoleTextFormatter : ITextFormatter
    {
        public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"<{GetSysLogLevel(logEvent.Level)}> {logEvent.Timestamp:O} [{GetThreeLetterLevel(logEvent.Level)}] - {logEvent.MessageTemplate}");
            if (logEvent.Exception != null)
                sb.AppendLine(logEvent.Exception.ToString());
            foreach (var property in logEvent.Properties.Where(p => p.Key != "SourceContext"))
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{property.Key}={property.Value}");
            }

            output.Write(sb.ToString());
        }

        // these are in a static class that I cannot access (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Formatting/Display/LevelOutputFormat.cs),
        // so I have hard coded them here
        private string GetThreeLetterLevel(LogEventLevel level)
        {
            return level switch
            {
                LogEventLevel.Debug => "DBG",
                LogEventLevel.Error => "ERR",
                LogEventLevel.Fatal => "FTL",
                LogEventLevel.Information => "INF",
                LogEventLevel.Verbose => "VRB",
                LogEventLevel.Warning => "WRN",
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown log level")
            };
        }

        private string GetSysLogLevel(LogEventLevel level)
        {
            return level switch
            {
                LogEventLevel.Debug => "7",
                LogEventLevel.Error => "3",
                LogEventLevel.Fatal => "2", // critical
                LogEventLevel.Information => "6",
                LogEventLevel.Verbose => "7",   // debug also
                LogEventLevel.Warning => "4",
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown log level")
            };
        }
```